# Is it possible to display images in IPython (or Jupyter) console?

Tags: python, jupyter, ipython, jupyter-console

I have just discovered that there are tools that allow embedding images into terminals, like [these ones](https://linuxhint.com/display-image-linux-terminal/).

I am wondering if there is a `IPython` (or, more generally `jupyter console`) builtin function that allows to do the same.  That would be handy for displaying plots inline.

I know you could do that with `QtConsole`, but that is not really a terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly in your console but in a new window:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

image = mpimg.imread('path/to/your/image.png')

# Display the image
plt.imshow(image)
plt.axis('off')  # remove the axis
plt.show()
```